# Use Google Protocol Buffer library in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers

I am using google-protobuf 3.0.0 beta-2 verion for javascript, use protoc compiler to create javascript classes out of my protobuf and in generated class pass bytes to deserializeBinary(bytes) method then did't get the expected result or values.

Comment: Nice plan you have. Please also share the exact code you are using and what you are expecting as result. This helps us help you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Veikko, first step: i have a buffer data like CgAaygUKAm1kEAItAAAAAC0AACBCLQAANEItAABIQi0AAFxCLQ; second step: decode it into basse64; third step:  convert base 64 decoded data into Uint8Array get the data in bytes; fourth step: pass Uint8Array bytes data to deserializeBinary(bytes) function  and final result is in string bytes which is not expected result, expected result is float data.  Result is: "
md-- B-4B-HB-\B-pB-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-Ȃ-҂-܂